# Turn off mod_security for a page in shared hosting environment

Tags: php, security, .htaccess

My page showing error forbidden access error,  when I post some `html` and `javascript` mixed data by other page post method .

but when I open that page directly its appears correctly without any error.

I know this is server security related issue when I am posting data.

As I searched I found the solution of **Turn off mod_security** in .`htaccess` file .

But I want to do this just for this page not for my complete website.

My hosing environment is shared.but I can edit my .`htaccess` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at some [mod_security and .htaccess tricks](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modsecurity-htaccess-tricks.html). There's a lot of different ways you can enable or disable mod_sceurity. The easiest may be to set the `MODSEC_ENABLE` environment variable to `On` or `Off`. You can use [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) to match against a number of things including the `Request_URI`:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI your_page\.php$ MODSEC_ENABLE=Off
```

Or a number of pages:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/directory/file.*\.php$ MODSEC_ENABLE=Off
```

Or if you need to do something more complicated, like matching against a query string, [using mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} example_param=example_value [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/your_file\.php$ - [E=MODSEC_ENABLE:Off]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the OWASP Core Rule set enabled?  Check your Apache error log to see which rule is matching.  You may find that it's blocking some of your legitimate users on other pages as well.  Talk to your hosting provider about what rule set they are using and what they are doing about false positives.

---

To solve your immediate problem, you can prevent a URI from being blocked by adding a new `SecRule` (and you can do this in your `.htaccess` file.

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/your/uri" "phase:1,pass"
```

To limit this to POST requests, you could use `REQUEST_LINE`:

```
SecRule REQUEST_LINE "POST /your/uri" "phase:1,pass"
```

Depending on what rule is matching and blocking the request currently, you may have to change those to `phase:2` or even add a second, identical rule with `phase:2`.